# Is it possible for MinecraftLauncher console to stay?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The Minecraft console disappears and the Minecraft Java game loads after the game output is loaded. Is it possible for it to stay? I would like to see the game output.

Comment: See [Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284651/see-loading-console-minecraft?rq=1) as this was just answered not long ago :)

Comment: @Nanobug that should be a duplicate of this question. Not surprising to see that the answer on that question is identical to the one on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit your profile to keep it open.
Click on the 'edit profile' button under the profile selector in the bottom left before clicking 'play'. This will bring up a dialog box. One of the options defaults to 'Close the launcher when the game opens'.
Change this to 'Keep the launcher open'.