# See Loading Console Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to be able to see all the steps my Minecraft is going through when it loads, through CMD or another Windows program. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your profile to keep the console open.
Click on the 'edit profile' button under the profile selector in the bottom left before clicking 'play'. This will bring up a dialog box. One of the options defaults to 'Close the launcher when the game opens'.
Change this to 'Keep the launcher open'.
[image]